# All Possible permutations of three to six different strings

Tags: arrays, algorithm, vb6, permutation

All, I have been beating my head against the wall for two days on this one. I have [googled](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=VB6+Build+list+of+all+possible+combinations#q=VB6+Build+list+of+all+possible+combinations&hl=en&prmd=ivns&ei=tloDTt79IoK0sAP2kYWHDg&start=30&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e2cdbf82a93ada0c&biw=1680&bih=925) and [googled](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=VB6+Build+list+of+all+possible+combinations#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=VB6+Build+list+of+all+possible+string+combinations&pbx=1&oq=VB6+Build+list+of+all+possible+string+combinations&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=44060l45451l0l7l7l0l0l0l4l305l1589l0.1.5.1l7&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e2cdbf82a93ada0c&biw=1680&bih=925) and I can't seem to find a solution. Here is what I have:

I have from two to six different string arrays (depending upon a user's selection) but for this question lets assume 3 separate string arrays:

- Array1 - Tom, Dick, Harry
- Array2 - Eats, Cooks, Drinks
- Array3 - Soup, Soda, Salad

I want the resulting Array to contain all possible combinations of these three string arrays but I don't want to combine the values contained in the same list (no: Tom Dick Harry). This is how I was the resulting array to look:

---

1. Tom Eats Soup
2. Tom Eats Soda
3. Tom Eats Salad
4. Dick Eats Soup
5. Dick Eats Soda
6. Dick Eats Salad
7. Harry Eats Soup
8. Harry Eats Soda
9. Harry Eats Salad

---

I'm looking for a VB6 solution but I would appreciate a solution or Algorithm in most any other programming language.

Thank you in advance for your helpful suggestions.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over an array? Do you know nested loops?

Comment: Yes, I am acquainted with Nested Loops and how to iterate through them but I am not able to wrap my mind around this one.

Comment: What about all of the permutations with Cooks and Drinks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is all you have to do, just do a triple-nested for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
         for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
             output array1[i] + " " array2[j] + " " + array3[k]; 
         }  
    }
}
```

You can translate to VB6. Modern languages like C# and VB.NET will let you express this more beautifully:

```
string[] names = new[] { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry" };
string[] verbs = new[] { "Eats", "Cooks", "Drinks" };
string[] foods = new[] { "Soup", "Soda", "Salad" };

var combinations = from name in names
                   from verb in verbs
                   from food in foods
                   select String.Join(" ", new[] { name, verb, food });

foreach(var combination in combinations) {
    Console.WriteLine(combination);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see my mistake was concatenating the string in the wrong spot.

Comment: I am unfortunately tasked with supporting a few legacy VB6 applications. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @Mark Kram: Unfortunately? Someone is willing to convert your time into money.

Comment: That is a good thing financially but it is tough to jump between DotNET stuff and VB6. It erodes your skill set a little.

Comment: Not really, there's a pretty ripe market for conversion from VB6 to .net, I wouldn't say that's an "eroding of skills".